# Тип собираемых библиотек по умолчанию

Tags: c++, cmake

По умолчанию у меня собираются статические библиотеки (если явно не указываю `SHARED` при создании библиотеки или `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` при запуске cmake), а как сделать так, чтобы по умалчанию собирались динамические библиотеки, если только не задано обратное (если к примеру `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=0`)?

Comment: Добавить `set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)` в свой CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @arrowd окей, допустим добавил - как теперь мне задать сборку статичиских библиотек? Опять лезть в CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Переконфигурировать: `cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF .`. Правда, `set()` надо будет вызывать с ключеым словом `CACHE`, наверное.

Comment: @arrowd хм, с CACHE может и заработает...